# Osmotic Pressure in Capillaries

Tags: blood-pressure, osmosis

In this diagram, D is apparently the point at which "the osmotic pressure into the capillaries is the greatest", but I cannot figure out why. Any help would be much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Homework questions are off-topic on Biology unless you have shown your attempt at an answer. For more information see our [homework policy](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework).

Answer (score 5):

Fluid movements across capillary wall is determined by 2 main factors.

- Hydrostatic Pressure (Blood Pressure) - tends to push fluid out of the blood vessel
- Osmotic Pressure - Tends to pull fluid back into the blood vessels mainly due to the presence of plasma proteins. (**especially** ***albumin***)

*Important points you should know*

- Hydrostatic pressure or blood pressure is the pressure exerted by blood on the capillary walls.
- Osmotic pressure depends on the number of osmotically active, non diffusible particles in the solutions separated by the membrane.
- The main substance responsible for the osmotic pressure between blood and tissue fluid are the plasma proteins. Especially **albumin**.
- Plasma proteins are absent in tissue fluid.

Filtration of fluids across capillaries is described by **Starling Forces**. (Forces were introduced by an English physiologist Ernest Starling.)

There are four main forces

1. Capillary Hydrostatic Pressure (P<sub>c</sub>) - This forces fluid out through the capillary membrane.
2. Interstitial Fluid Pressure (P<sub>if</sub>) - Tends to force fluid from interstitial spaces across capillary membrane
3. Capillary Plasma Colloid Osmotic Pressure (∏<sub>p</sub>) - Tends to cause osmosis of fluid inward through capillary membrane.
4. Interstitial Fluid Colloid Osmotic Pressure (∏<sub>if</sub>) - Tends to cause osmosis of fluid outward through capillary membrane. -**Negligible**

[image]

According to Starling forces,
Filtration = k (P<sub>c</sub> - P<sub>if</sub>) - (∏<sub>p</sub> - ∏<sub>if</sub>)

Filtration = k x ***Net Filtration pressure***

Here k is the *capillary filtration coefficient* which is depend on permeability of capillary wall and surface area for filtration.

Look at the following diagram
[image]

In **your** diagram **A** is the **Arteriole** end and **D** is the **Venous** end.

Now we can calculate **Net Filtration Pressure** at A and D.

### At Arteriole end (A);

- ### Outward forces are;

### Capillary hydrostatic pressure (P<sub>c</sub>) = **37 mm Hg**

and

### Interstitial Fluid Colloid Osmotic Pressure (∏<sub>if</sub>) = *0 mm Hg*

*So outwards force is 37 mm Hg.*

### Inward forces are;

### Capillary Plasma Colloid Osmotic Pressure (∏<sub>p</sub>) = **25 mm Hg**

and

### Interstitial Fluid Pressure (P<sub>if</sub>) = **1 mm Hg**.

*So inward force is 26 mm Hg.*

### **Therefore net force is 37 - 26 = 11 mm Hg** **and it is** ***outwards.***

---

### At Venous end (D);

### Outwards forces;

### Capillary hydrostatic pressure (P<sub>c</sub>) = **17 mm Hg**

and

### Interstitial Fluid Colloid Osmotic Pressure (∏<sub>if</sub>) = *0 mm Hg*

*So outwards force is 17 mm Hg.*

### Inward forces are;

### Capillary Plasma Colloid Osmotic Pressure (∏<sub>p</sub>) = **25 mm Hg**

and

### Interstitial Fluid Pressure (P<sub>if</sub>) = **1 mm Hg**.

*So inward force is 26 mm Hg.*

### **Therefore net force is 26 - 17 = 9 mm Hg** **and it is** ***inwards.***

So that's why

> In this diagram, D is apparently the point at which "the osmotic pressure into the capillaries is the greatest"